# Can orchard modules be in separate folder?

Tags: orchardcms

Is it possible to have the orchard modules in a completely separate folder from the website , so that more than one orchard site can share the files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you write your own extension loader. For the moment there is one for themes, one for core modules and one for modules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm quite new to orchard so not too sure how to approach writing an extention loader. Interestingly I was able to get the site working by putting the modules folder in a virtual directory in IIS, however looks like you then loose the ability to install new modules.

Comment: Ah, yes, that should work as well, if you put all the modules there. But if you're doing that, you might as well have only one Orchard instance and use multi-tenancy.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will explore that solution.